# Using the Manage Styles in ASP.NET for CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I create a style in the manage styles window. Named it h1 and then tried to add it onto some text (color red, large font size etc) . It shows up correctly in the windows VS program, but as soon as it display in a browser from debugging it, The h1 style isn't showing up.

Also when i add a  black solid line border on my #page style, and apply it to a div tag, the border isn't showing up. Some help please.

```
#page
    {
        border: thin solid #000000;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: White;
    }

      h1
      {
    font-size: large;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
`
```

Above is what i have written in a style sheet for the style properties.

Comment: Does style sheet even render to front end? You can see it in browser - view source.

Comment: Yes I'm debugging it thru internet explorer from from VS.

Comment: It's almost as if something else is overriding the external style sheet i wrote, like a default for h1 i don't know about. As well as a default for #page.

Comment: View my answer below, it might not be the correct answer but I put it there so its easy to read, try it. if it works, then we know that it is your call to your css file.

Comment: You did not answer my question. If the style sheet is not rendered to browser, doesn't matter what you put in the style sheet you won't see your style in the browser.

Comment: When i debug it, the solution render the web form i'm using through local host into my web browser, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your CSS in its own file, if so make sure you are linking it correctly. If you add your code we can show you how.

To debug you can put your styles in the `<head></head>` section of your html, while it tends to get cluttered up there, its not a good idea to keep it there but it will work. like this:

```
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    font-size: large;
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#page { 
    border: thin solid #000000; 
    width: 400px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 20px; 
    background-color: White; 
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: I have my own created style sheet. I'm calling it though`<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Thats fine, put the `<style></style>` into your `head>` if it works, we know that it is your file location, if it doesn't work it is because you have something over ridding it or you are calling your tags incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, so at least you know that it is or was an issue with your file location. If you do not have much more styling to do you can leave it there, but if you are creating a whole page it might be a good idea to debug your your css file and location.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Invoice Total</title>
<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        height: 18.4em;
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 398px;
    }
</style>
 </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id="page" class="auto-style1">

    <h1>Invoice Total Calculator</h1>
```

Comment: Is your Main.css capitalized on the file? and is it saved to the same folder?

Comment: It's in the same project same folder as my default.aspx. My solution folder.